# Prove that $p_n$ is always an integer and that $(p_n,p_{n+1},p_{n+2})$ is independent of $n$

Tags: polynomials

Let $x_1,x_2,x_3$ be the roots of $$x^3+ax^2+bx-1=0$$ Where $a$ and $b$ are integers.

Define $p_n=x_1^n+x_2^n+x_3^n$. Prove that $p_n$ is always an integer and that $\gcd(p_n,p_{n+1},p_{n+2})$ is independent of $n$.

Here is my work so far,

By definition of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ we have  $$x^3+ax^2+bx-1 =(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)$$ Which gives the following  $$a=-(x_1+x_2+x_3), \quad b=x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3$$
And $$x_1x_2x_3=1$$
Now I’m stuck. I tried to use the usual substitution of $x_1=a/b,x_2=b/c...$ But it didn’t help plus I have no idea behind the definition of $p_n.$

Comment: Prove that $p_n$ is an integer when $n=0$, $n=1$ and $n=2$, then make a recursion. In a same way, note that if $n \ge 1$, the common divisors of $p_n,p_{n+1},p_{n+2}$ are also the common divisors of $p_{n-1},p_n,p_{n+1}$.

Comment: Do you know how to find a linear recurrence for $p_n?$ You then only need to show $p_0,p_1,p_2$ are integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By multiplying the equation $x^3 + ax^2 + bx - 1 = 0$ by $x^n$ and adding the equations up for $x_1, x_2, x_3$, we get $p_{n+3} + ap_{n+2} + bp_{n+1} - p_n = 0$. So for all $n \geq 0$, we have $p_{n+3} = -ap_{n+2} - bp_{n+1} + p_n$. Because $p_0 = x_1^0 + x_2^0 + x_3^0 = 3, p_1 = x_1^1 + x_2^1 + x_3^1 = -a$ and $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 = (x_1 + x_2 + x_3)^2 - 2(x_1x_2 + x_2x_3 + x_3x_1) = a^2 - 2b$ are integers, so using the recursion and induction on $n$ will prove that $p_n$ is always an integer.

For the second part, notice that
$$\mathrm{gcd}(p_{n+2}, p_{n+1}, p_n) = \mathrm{gcd}(-ap_{n+1} - bp_n + p_{n-1}, p_{n+1}, p_n) = \mathrm{gcd}(p_{n+1}, p_n, p_{n-1}).$$
So for all $n \geq 0$, the number $\mathrm{gcd}(p_{n+2}, p_{n+1}, p_n)$ equals $\mathrm{gcd}(p_2, p_1, p_0) = \mathrm{gcd}(a^2 - 2b, -a, 3)$ and is independent of $n$.

Comment: So the gcd divides $ p_o=3$ Hence it’s either $1$ or$3$.